# Can I view the format history of a usb key?

Tags: hardware, forensics, usb

Is there a way to view when changes were made to a USB key, such as when the USB key was formatted and/or when some files were transferred?

I have seen this previous stackexchange question [File system history on USB drives](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26686/file-system-history-on-usb-drives), but it wasnt clear if anywhere on the USB key a log will be available.

NB. I only have the USB key at hand.

Comment: I'm don't quite understand the question, do you want a method to track which user did something with the usb? or do you want to know the exact logs of the usb?

Comment: In the linked question, that information is not available. NTFS does not track who deleted a file. Even if a file-system _tried_ to track that info, as a first-pass guess I think it would be very hard to (a) prevent someone falsifying the records, and (b) at best you'd only know the _username_ under which the deletion occurred, not necessarily the actual _person_ behind the keyboard.

Comment: It won't be to track, but more _ex tunc_ view if somebody did transfer some files and/or format the drive. A date of previous formatting would actually already be a good indicator. So, more something towards logs of the USB.

Comment: Does the USB device have an internal log? No.

Comment: Note that even if the USB _did_ have a log, the results may be misleading or wrong, even non-maliciously.  For instance, Unix/Linux based systems store file permissions/etc with a **numeric id**, and usually the first id assigned on pretty much all systems is going to be `1000`.  So you look at the logs and go... "I did this?"  Even a textual id could be wrong if two people happen to use the same username on their system.